# How to select distinct values in a pair?

Tags: sql, sqlite

If I have the following table:

> 1,1
>
> 1,2
>
> 2,2
>
> 2,3

then how do I select only distinct pair values like:

> 1,2
>
> 2,3

eliminating only pairs which have the same value?

Comment: `<>` stands for "not equals".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
table
row1 row2
1     1
1     2
2     2
2     3
```

Try this query

select * from table where row1 <> row2

Comment: I will be grateful if you mark my answer as userful